# Setting up a poll watcher using notify example

Tags: rust, notify

The notify documentation is great for raw and debounced events. There is mention of a poll watcher implementation but I cannot seem to set this up. Would anyone be able to point me or provide some sample code? Either for a raw or debounced method?

I have a mount drive I am trying to watch through Linux and the inotify instance is picking up no events so my only option is to try to poll.

Heres my current code for the debounced

```
extern crate notify;
extern crate weighted_rs;

use notify::{Watcher, RecursiveMode, watcher};
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::path::Path;
use std::fs;
use weighted_rs::{SmoothWeight, Weight};

fn main() {
// Create a channel to receive the events.
let (tx, rx) = channel();

// Create a watcher object, delivering debounced events.
// The notification back-end is selected based on the platform.
let mut watcher = watcher(tx, Duration::from_secs(5)).unwrap();

// Add a path to be watched. All files and directories at that path 
and
// below will be monitored for changes.
//watcher.watch("/mnt/jobs_testwatch/", 
RecursiveMode::NonRecursive).unwrap();
watcher.watch("/mnt/jobs/", RecursiveMode::NonRecursive).unwrap();

let mut sw: SmoothWeight<&str> = SmoothWeight::new();
sw.add("w1", 1);
sw.add("w2", 1);
sw.add("w3", 1);

loop {
    match rx.recv() {
        Err(e) => println!("watch error: {:?}", e),
       Ok(event) => {
       println!("{:?}", event);
       match event{
           notify::DebouncedEvent::NoticeWrite(_) => {}
           notify::DebouncedEvent::NoticeRemove(_) => {}
           notify::DebouncedEvent::Write(_) => {},
           notify::DebouncedEvent::Chmod(_) => {},
           notify::DebouncedEvent::Remove(_) => {}
           notify::DebouncedEvent::Rename(_, _) => {}
           notify::DebouncedEvent::Rescan => {}
           notify::DebouncedEvent::Error(_, _) => {},
           notify::DebouncedEvent::Create(x) => {
               println!("{:?}", x);
               let path_gen = Path::new(&x);
               let file_stem = path_gen.file_stem().unwrap();
               let extension = path_gen.extension();
               //println!("filestem = {:?}, extension = {:?}", 
file_stem, extension);
               if extension != None {
                //println!("event = {:?} -- Path = {:?}", op, path);    
                //println!("filename =>{:?}, extension =>{:?}", 
file_stem, extension.unwrap());
                //println!("");
                //let xml_string =  OsStr::new("xml");
                match extension.unwrap().to_str(){
                    Some("xml")=>{
                        println!("found {:?}.", extension.unwrap());
                        let s = sw.next().unwrap();
                        println!("moving to /{} ...", s);
                        let movepath = format! 
        ("/mnt/jobs/lbalancewatchers/{}/{}.xml",s, 
        file_stem.to_str().unwrap());
                        let foo = fs::read_to_string(&x);
                        match foo{
                            Ok(_) => {
                             let a = fs::rename(&x, &movepath);
                             if let Err(e) = a {
                                 println!("error moving file --> 
{}", e)
                             }
                             println!("moved {:?} to {:?}", 
&file_stem, &movepath)},

                             //println!("{:#?}", foo.unwrap())},
                            Err(_) => println!("")
                        }
                             
                        //println!("{:#?}", foo)
                     }
                    _ => {println!("{:?} is NOT an xml" , 
extension)}
                }
            };
            
            
            },
               
            
       }
    }

}
}
```

}

Comment: What sort of mount is it?  "*Inotify reports only events that a user-space program triggers through the filesystem API.  As a result, it does not catch remote events that occur on network filesystems... Furthermore, various pseudo-filesystems such as /proc, /sys, and /dev/pts are not monitorable with inotify.  The inotify API does not report file accesses and modifications that may occur because of mmap(2), msync(2), and munmap(2).*" -- https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html

Comment: Have you tried [`PollWatcher::with_delay_ms`](https://docs.rs/notify/4.0.16/notify/poll/struct.PollWatcher.html#method.with_delay_ms)?

Comment: Our guys who do our hardware set it up. I think its a samba share. The really odd thing is the raw watcher in notify picks up the events but it picks them up too fast before windows has finished writing and the whole thing errors. The debounced watcher gets nothing. I would expect if the raw gets them the debounced would but apparently not. I thought the polling option might be a workaround but I can’t seem to set it up however much I try. Apologies I am somewhat new to Rust

Comment: I haven’t tried the pollwatcher...I can’t seem to get a working example up. I must be missing something but as a newbie to rust I seem to be hitting a wall.

Comment: I've added the whole script to the orginal so you can see where I am currently at. It basically pulls xml files and then load balances them to other folders that are all running javascript watchers

Comment: for anyone hitting this it was a simple solution the line should read:    let mut watcher= PollWatcher::new(tx, Duration::from_secs(5)).unwrap();

Comment: I had put Pollwatcher without the ::new and missed that it needed instantiating with ::new as I thought it was a function call not a class. Looking through the docs it was a function that calls a class and it needed the ::new. Felt a little silly once it clicked so apologies for anyone who read this and clearly knew my mistake!